# Como limitar a quantidade de casas decimais no dart?

Tags: dart

Como faço para limitar a quantidade de casas decimais exibidas? Como faço para que esse valor `15.592783505154639Kg` fique igual a  `15.59Kg` usando dart?

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  CalculoIMC();
}

CalculoIMC(){

  stdout.write("Digite a sua massa: ");
  var massa = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
  var altura = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  var IMC = massa / (altura * 2);

  if (IMC < 16){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, MUITO ABAIXO DO PESO");
  } else if (IMC > 16 && IMC < 17){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, MAGREZA MODERADA");
  } else if (IMC > 17 && IMC < 18.5){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, MAGREZA LEVE");
  } else if (IMC > 18.5 && IMC < 25){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, SAUDÁVEL");
  } else if (IMC > 25 && IMC < 30){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, SOBREPESO");
  } else if (IMC > 30 && IMC < 35){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU I");
  } else if (IMC > 35 && IMC < 40){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU II");
  } else if (IMC >= 40){
    print("Você está com $IMC\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU III");
  }

}
```

Comment: Use o [método `num#toStringAsFixed()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de definir a quantidade de casas decimais é usando o [`toStringAsFixed`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html), como ele você converte um valor decimal em `string` (texto), nele você deve passar o `fractionDigits` que define quantas casas decimais.

No código abaixo eu criei uma nova variável para armenzenar o valor formatado do `IMC` e inseri essa valor nos textos que apresenta as resposta para o usuário.

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  CalculoIMC();
}

CalculoIMC(){

  stdout.write("Digite a sua massa: ");
  var massa = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
  var altura = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  var IMC = massa / (altura * 2);

  var IMCFormatado = IMC.toStringAsFixed(2);
  
  if (IMC < 16){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, MUITO ABAIXO DO PESO");
  } else if (IMC > 16 && IMC < 17){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, MAGREZA MODERADA");
  } else if (IMC > 17 && IMC < 18.5){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, MAGREZA LEVE");
  } else if (IMC > 18.5 && IMC < 25){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, SAUDÁVEL");
  } else if (IMC > 25 && IMC < 30){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, SOBREPESO");
  } else if (IMC > 30 && IMC < 35){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU I");
  } else if (IMC > 35 && IMC < 40){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU II");
  } else if (IMC >= 40){
    print("Você está com $IMCFormatado\Kg, OBESIDADE GRAU III");
  }

}
```

Comment: Deu certo, vlw ai.